# Rashis unknown family

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, rashi, pinchas, levites-leviyim

Rashi in parshas Pinchos (Bamidbar 26,13) with regards to a son of Shimon which was missing from the previous count in Parshas Bamidbar quotes the Yerushalmi which addresses this question:

> משפחת אהד בטלה וכן חמש משבט בנימין שהרי בעשרה בנים ירד למצרים וכאן לא מנה אלא חמשה וכן אצבון לגד הרי שבע משפחות ומצאתי בגמ' ירושלמית שכשמת אהרן נסתלקו ענני כבוד ובאו הכנענים להלחם בישראל ונתנו לב לחזור למצרים וחזרו לאחוריהם ח' מסעות מהר ההר למוסרה שנא' (דברים י) ובני ישראל נסעו מבארות בני יעקן מוסרה שם מת אהרן והלא בהר ההר מת וממוסרה עד הר ההר שמונה מסעות יש למפרע אלא שחזרו לאחוריהם ורדפו בני לוי אחריהם להחזירם והרגו מהם שבע משפחות ומבני לוי נפלו ארבע משפחות משפחת שמעי ועזיאלי ומבני יצהר לא נמנו כאן אלא משפחת קרחי והרביעית לא ידעתי מה היא

In summary 11 families in total perished.
1 from Shimon: Ohad
1 from Gad: Etzbon
5 from Binyomin: Becher, Ard, naamon, Geira, Rosh
4 from Levi: Shimi, Uziel, ?

My question: If Rashi says only Korach was left out of the sons of Yitzhar, since Yitzhar had 3 sons that leaves 2 families Nepheg and Zichri missing, plus the 2 families of Shimi and Uziel which adds up to 4.
So why does Rashi say he only knows 3 families?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent question - here is how Rashi should be understood based on the Mefarshei Rashi, such as Mizrachi, who I quote below.

In short, Nepheg and Zichri are not considered Mishpachos of their own, since they are a generation below the other missing Mishpachos. Combined, they show that Yitzhar (one family) is lacking (since most of his children are missing/dead).  Therefore, the fourth family is still unknown.

The source for the fact that only those 8 grandchildren of Levi are considered Mishpachos is mentioned in the Mizrachi below, and based on what they are called in Parshas Bamidbar.  The bolded text is the answer to your question.

Mizrachi (available [here](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bemidbar/26.13#e0n7)) says:

> ומבני לוי נפלו ארבע משפחות משפחת השמעי ועזיאלי ומבני יצהר לא נמנו כאן אלא משפחת הקרחי והרביעי לא ידעתי מה היא. פירוש מהשמנה משפחות של בני לוי שהן לגרשון לבני ושמעי ולקהת עמרם ויצהר וחברון ועוזיאל ולמררי מחלי ומושי האמורות בפרשת במדבר לא נזכרו כאן לא משפחת שמעי ולא משפחת עוזיאלי ולא משפחת יצהרי שהרי ליצהר שלשה בנים היו לו קרח ונפג וזכרי ולא נזכר מהם רק משפחת הקרחי וכיון שבטלו רוב משפחת יצהרי הרי הוא כאילו בטלו כל משפחת יצהרי הרי כאן שלש משפחות חסרות ממשפחות לוי אבל הרביעית לא ידעתי מה היא **וא״ת מאחר שלא נמנו כאן מבני יצהר אלא משפחת הקרחי נימא שהד׳ משפחות שחסרו משבט לוי הן שמעי ועזיאלי ושני בני יצהר שהם נפג וזכרי י״ל שהמשפחות של לוי אינן אלא אותן הח׳ האמורות בפרשת במדבר ששם פי׳ ואמר אלה הם משפחות הלוי לגרשון משפחת הלבני ומשפחת השמעי אלה הם משפחות הגרשוני ולקהת משפחת העמרמי ומשפחת היצהרי ומשפחת החברוני ומשפחת העזיאלי אלה הם משפחות הקהתי ולמררי משפחת המחלי ומשפחת המושי אלה הם משפחות מררי הרי שגלה בפי׳ שאלה הח׳ משפחות לבד הן משפחות לוי ולא משפחה אחרת ואם כן נפג וזכרי אינן קרויין משפחות של לוי** ואין טענה ממשפחת הקרחי שאינה מכלל הח׳ משפחות האמורות בפרשת במדבר ואפי׳ הכי קורא אותה משפחת הקרחי וכלל אותה הכתוב בכלל משפחת הלוי כאמרו בתחלה אלה משפחות הלוי דקרחי דהכא במקום יצהרי היא אך קשה דאם כן כיון דבמקום יצהרי היא לא חסרו משבט לוי רק שתי משפחות משפחת שמעי ומשפחת עזיאלי ואיך כתב רש״י והרביעי׳ לא ידעתי מה הוא ושמא יש לומר דאף על גב דקרחי במקום יצהרי הוא מ״מ כיון דמבני יצהר לא נמנו כאן אלא משפחת הקרחי שהיא משפח׳ אחת מהשלש משפחות היצהרי שבטלו רוב משפחות יצהרי הרי הוא כאילו בטלה כל משפחות יצהרי ואם כן הרי שלשה משפחות חסרות מלוי:

Comment: It's a bit odd though, because all the other "families" mentioned are children, not grandchildren.

Comment: +1 thanks amazing website source! while this is the right answer does anyone argue with Rashi and say the 4 families include Nepheg and Zichri?

Comment: @alex levi seems to have a different standing for "family status" - for example, all of his children got counted, whereas none of the other shevatim's children got counted...

Comment: @user15464 yes, this is an amazing website.  check the yerushlmi in the sources rashi quotes from (open the English translation for rashi at the link above), maybe the mefarshei yerushalmi hold that way.